# How can I groupby in Python, by a finding a certain word that may be in multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the average numbers of impressions for when a certain hashtag appears in a tweet. The problem is that I have separate columns for each tag, but some of the words, for example, may be tag 1 in some cases and tag 3 in another. How can I groupby a certain word, even if it appears in different columns in a data frame. (a word will never appear multiple times in the same row). I have tried grouping by each column individually, and then joining them, but that made me run into a load of other problems. Is there a better approach? [This is what the tag columns look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCdDy.png) I want to group by a column called 'impressions' and find the average number of impressions when a given tag appears (i.e. 'cloud' may be tag 1 or tag 2 or tag 9, but I want the code to recognize all the tweets that contain the cloud tag, and then do the group by)

Comment: Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Melt the tag columns into a single column which would be your groupby column. Then do the grouby.

```
df.melt(id_vers = ['impressions',..etc], value_vars=['tag1','tag2','tag3',..etc],var_name='MainTag')
df.groupby('MainTag')['impressions'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot you have a column the you split and fill in several columns called "tag" with whatever would have a hashtag before it. Although I don't have a solution (with this code) that will look through all the columns that are "tags" columns, This will let you know if anything in the "split" column contains cloud

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : ['Thursday', 'Thursday'],
    'Column2' : [['#Snowflake', '#Cloud'], ['#Snowflake', '#Azure']]
})

df['Cloud_IND'] = df['Column2'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x)).str.contains('Cloud')
df
```